# Why can't I use a ternary operator and arrow function in this way in JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, jsx

With `babel-preset-react` (EDIT: babel version: `v6.26.0`), the following expression fails with the error "`Invalid left-hand side in arrow function parameters`" ([try on babel repl](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=C4JwrgpgBA_FAUAiYEDOxEEooC4oA8oBeAPigBYAmIA&debug=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact&prettier=false&targets=Electron-0.3%252CNode-7.4&version=6.26.0)):

```
true ? ("test") : x => 42      //FAILS, but only with `babel-preset-react`
```

Yet it works given a small modification:

```
true ? "test" : x => 42        //works fine
```

Both of these scenarios work as expected in seemingly any other configuration.

Is this a bug? Or is there something as a part of JSX parsing that causes this to happen?

Comment: Likely this has to do with precedence of operators. Can you give a **complete** example that causes the error?

Comment: What are you looking for in a **complete** example? I've attempted to reduce the expression to the smallest example possible already.

Comment: This does sound like a bug for an EcmaScript parser indeed, a grouping parenthesis should be valid in every position where a string literal is valid. However, jsx or typescript or flow may have problems with the colon following the parenthesis.

Comment: Sounds like a parser bug. Does this work? `true ? ("test") : (x => 42)`

Comment: @ArashMotamedi That works both with and without `babel-preset-react`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug. I've created an issue on the babel github page: [babel/babel#7234](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/7234). It is fixed in Babel 7.

Answer (score 3):

Arrow functions are parsed differently than regular ones
see [Parsing order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Parsing_order)

> Although the arrow in an arrow function is not an operator, arrow
>   functions have special parsing rules that interact differently with
>   operator precedence compared to regular functions.

```
let callback;

callback = callback || function() {}; // ok

callback = callback || () => {};      
// SyntaxError: invalid arrow-function arguments

callback = callback || (() => {});    // ok
```

It must have something to do with associativity of ternary operator (right-to-left) see [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table)

Comment: Good to know. The examples you've given don't change behavior when using `babel-preset-react`, though.

Comment: Yup, this is all correct and a common thing that people catch on, but it does not apply to the comma operator and conditional operator since their operands are allowed to contain arrows.

Answer (score 1):

The simple reason for this is that anything within `()` is treated as an `condition` to evaluate and hence it tries to find matching expressions after it which you aren't providing and hence it fails. As a matter of fact

```
true ? ("test")? 1: 2 : x => 42
```

compiles just fine into

```
"use strict";

true ? "test" ? 1 : 2 : function (x) {
  return 42;
};
```

Check **[this demo](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=C4JwrgpgBA_FAUAiYEDOxEEo4EYBcUATFAQB5QC8AfFACyFA&debug=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact&prettier=false&targets=Electron-0.3%252CNode-7.4&version=6.26.0)**

Comment: In the examples I've given though, I'm not using `("test")` as a condition. it is `expression1` of the ternary operator `condition ? expression1 : expression2`. Is there something as part of JSX that causes it to be parsed as a condition instead?

Comment: As I said writing it within parenthesis makes babel think it's a condition

Comment: Wrapping the "test" in parenthesis doesn't seem to be the only reason babel is confused. I can also wrap the arrow function in parenthesis (`true ? ("test") : (x => 42)`) to fix the issue.