# Nullish coalescing operator in object not working but ternary does

Tags: javascript

I have an object that has a `selector` property which should receive a function callback:

```
{
  selector: (element) => element.name
}
```

but I want to conditionally pick another callback function for the `selector` via the `??` operator from another object:

```
const extendedCallback = {
  example: (element) => element.another
}
```

so what I do is:

```
{
  selector: extendedCallback.example ?? (element) => element.name
}
```

but then my IDE says `Cannot find name 'element'.ts(2304)` for the right handed side of the operator. When I do the same with ternary:

```
'example' in extendedCallback ? extendedCallback.example : (element) => element.name
```

it works fine. What is a misconception I have about the `??` ?

Comment: Operator precedence: `extendedCallback.example ?? ((element) => element.name)`

Comment: @VLAZ sometimes one can't see the wood for the trees. Definitely need more caffeine! Thank you.

Comment: Related: [Why does the logical or operator (||) with an empty arrow function (()=>{}) cause a SyntaxError?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42679078) | [How to use arrow function with || operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39795104) | [What is the exact parsing precedence of arrow function (fat arrow =>) in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50461820) | [Why can't I use a ternary operator and arrow function in this way in JSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48309694)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), `=>` has lower precedence than `??` so your code gets interpreted as

```
(extendedCallback.example ?? (element)) => element.name
```

You need to use parentheses to get the correct operation.

```
selector: extendedCallback.example ?? ((element) => element.name)
```